# Programatically generating web console URL to s3 object

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, boto, botocore

Is there a way to generate urls to the s3 web console (https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/...) within python using botocore or boto3? I know boto can be used to generate presigned urls, but is there a way to just generate URL to the webconsole?

Comment: No, you have to construct it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way in boto3 to generate the url but you can easily generate them yourself with variables and string formatting.

```
print("https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/{}?region={}&tab=objects".format("bucket_name", "us-east-1"))
```